# Get last record of Table in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I Have a table of projects and reports that reports table save many reports of project in every day. Now, I want to get last reports date property of project I'm using this code in controller:

```
 $res = Project::with(['reports' => function($query){
            $query->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->first();
        }])->get();
        return view ('home',compact('res'));
```

And in view I have this code:

```
@foreach(Auth::user()->projects as $project)
  @if($res->date == Now())
     <p>hi</p>
 @else
    <p>By</p>
@endforeach
```

But I get this Error:
`Property [date] does not exist on this collection instance`
and return $res in view I give this jason:

```
{"id":51,"user_id":21,"name":"dff","description":"fff","price":4444,"status":0,"darsad":4,"start_time":"1396-08-18","finish_time":"1396-08-29","created_at":"2017-11-19 08:22:39","updated_at":"2017-11-19 08:22:39","reports":[{"id":20,"user_id":21,"project_id":51,"date":"96\/09\/06","description":"vvvv","created_at":"2017-11-27 11:19:43","updated_at":"2017-11-27 11:19:43"}]}
```

How can I get last reports of any projects?

Comment: `$res` is an instance of `Project`

Comment: Are you sure that you are getting the response from the query? If so could you provide with response here?

Comment: @user7325973 Please check Edit Question

Comment: @user7325973 Please check Edit Question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your requirement is just to display the latest single record. This below method can be given a shot.

Controller Snippet:

```
$res = Project::orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->get();
return view ('home',compact('res'));
```

Blade Snippet:

```
    @foreach ($res as $data)
        @if ($loop->first)
            @if($data->reports[0]->date == Now())
              <p>hi</p>
            @else
              <p>By</p>
            @endif

        @endif
    @endforeach
```

Comment: I give this error in check if Field 'date' not found in arra

Comment: Edited check now.

Answer (score 0):

Hayy...you are trying to compare undefined value because the **date** is part of reports array in your response. So you can't directly access date from your response.Better try to use the below snippet instead of ur blade. It tries to access reports and then access date from reports.

```
@foreach(Auth::user()->projects as $project)
  @if($res->reports[0]->date == Now())
     <p>hi</p>
 @else
    <p>By</p>
 @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Whats is your error response. Could you check now i added endif. If you are still facing issue . could you provide the error ?